# How to change the context of this inside object

Tags: javascript

I want to access a function which is outside my base object, but if we console.log(this) inside loadAll function then it will give the context inside object. If I console.log(this) any normal function i.e without action or getter/setters it will give context of whole class which I want to achieve

```
base = observable({
         isDeleting: false,
         registry: observable.map(),
         get all() {
            return this.registry.values();
          },
         loadAll:action.bound(function () {
            console.log(this);
            this.request()
         }),
       });
request = () => { 
console.log('hello');
}
```

In The above example this will throw an error because it can't access the request function but I wan to find a way to access it.

```
base = observable({
             isDeleting: false,
             registry: observable.map(),
             get all() {
                return this.registry.values();
              },
             loadAll:action.bound(function () {
                console.log(this);
                this.request()
             }),
             request: () => { 
                console.log(this) //This will give context of all the function outside object that is what I want in above example.
                console.log('hello');
               },
           });
```

Comment: Hello, as far as I tried, code below shows and error as well. I'm not 100% sure what are you trying to show us with it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.